# Retrieving numbers from WhatsApp group members list through Accessibility in android and java

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am retrieving names and numbers from member list of whats app group with the help of given code.

```
    public void GroupExtract(AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo) {
    // GroupName = saif.toString();
    int i = 0;
    String strnum;
    System.out.println("Group groupback=" + groupback);
    String str;
    String str2;
    String str3;
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId = accessibilityNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/group_chat_info_layout_root");
    int size = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId != null ? findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() : 0;
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = this.f7525f;
    if (size > 0) {

        String str4 = "";
        String str5 = str4;
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo next : findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId) {

            try {
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2 = next.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/name");
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId3 = next.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/secondary_name_view");
                //for (int j = 0; i < next.getChildCount(); j++){

                    if ((findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2 != null ? findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.size() : 0) == 1) {
                        if ((findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId3 != null ? findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId3.size() : 0) == 1) {

                            str2 = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId3.get(0).getText().toString();
                            str = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.get(0).getText().toString().startsWith("~") ? findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.get(0).getText().toString().substring(1) : findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.get(0).getText().toString();
                        } else {
                            str2 = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.get(0).getText().toString();
                            str = "";
                        }
                        //i = j + 1;
                        //sleep(1000);
                        try {
                            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId4 = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId2.get(0).getParent().findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/push_name");
                            if ((findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId4 != null ? findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId4.size() : 0) == 1) {
                                str3 = findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId4.get(0).getText().toString().replace("~", "");
                                Log.i(TAG, "number ==>" + str2 + ", name ==>" + str3);
                                System.out.println("number ==>" + str2 + ", name ==>" + str3);
                                String str6 = str3;
                                // str5 = str2;
                                //str4 = str6;
                                // sleep(1000);
                            }





                        str3 = str;
                        Log.i(TAG, "number ==>" + str2 + ", name ==>" + str3);
                        System.out.println("number ==>" + str2 + ", name ==>" + str3);
                        String str62 = str3;
                        str5 = str2;
                        str4 = str62;
                        strnum = str2;

                        if (GroupNumber.isEmpty())
                            GroupNumber = strnum;

                        else if (!GroupNumber.contains(strnum))

                            GroupNumber = GroupNumber + " , " + strnum;
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {

                        }
                    }

               // }

                Log.i(TAG, "phoneMap.size() is ==>" + hashMap.size() + " waste counter is " + this.M + " number is==>" + str5);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str5)) {
                    if (!hashMap.containsKey(str5)) {
                        hashMap.put(str5, str4);
                        sleep(1500);
                        strnum = str5;
                        this.M = 0;

                    } else {

                        //this.M++;
                        //sleep(500);
                        System.out.println("Number=>" + GroupNumber);
                        //sleep(200);
                        groupback = true;
                        //performGlobalAction(1);
                        sleep(2500);
                        performGlobalAction(1);
                        sleep(500);
                        performGlobalAction(1);
                        // sleep(200);
                        performGlobalAction(1);
                        listshow = false;
                        // sleep(200);
                        // performGlobalAction(1);
                        //sleep(20);
                        //goBack(accessibilityNodeInfo);
                    }


                }

                findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() - 1).getParent().performAction(ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);

            } catch (Exception e10) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception occured" + e10.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            //  findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() - 1).getParent().performAction(ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);

        }


    }


}
```

The code seems to work correctly and it is showing some numbers and names of group members in the list.
But I need some help to make this code work correctly.
1- If the number of group members is assumed to be 100, then this code sometimes shows us the list of 20 members and sometimes 32 members etc.
2- I want that when selecting a Whats App group, it will check each item in the list of individuals and show us its name and number respectively. And the numbers that are being obtained are being double shown in the list. Please seniors help for correcting this code.